# Access inner text of component tags that is not a component or html tag?

Tags: angular, angular2-template

Here is an example:

```
var ListItem = ng.core.Component({
    selector: "item",
    inputs: ["title"],
    template: "<li>{{title}} | <ng-content></ng-content></li>",
}).Class({
    constructor: function(){}
})

var ListOne = ng.core.Component({
    selector: "listone",
    queries: {
        list_items: new ng.core.ContentChildren(ListItem)
    },
    directives: [ListItem],
    template: "<ul><ng-content select='item'></ng-content></ul>"
}).Class({
    constructor: function(){},
    ngAfterContentInit: function(){
        console.log(this.list_items);
    }
})
```

And then I am using this code to display the components:

```
<listone>
    <item title="first">first</item>
    <item title="second">second</item>
</listone>
```

How can `ngAfterContentInit` of `ListOne` component access innerHTML of `<item>` tags?

I want a solution without wrapping the inner text with another tag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This needs a bit support of the `ItemComponent`:

```
export class ItemComponent {
  title: 'title';
  constructor(public elementRef:ElementRef){}
}
```

For the `@ContentChildren()` we set `descendants: true`:

```
export class ListoneComponent {
  @ContentChildren(ItemComponent, {descendants: true}) list_items;

  ngAfterContentInit() {
    this.list_items.toArray().forEach((item) => {
      console.log(item.elementRef.nativeElement.innerHTML);
    })
  }
}
```

[**Plunker example**](https://plnkr.co/edit/acJCFV?p=preview)

I hope TypeScript code is still helpful, I don't know how to use Angular with ESx.

Comment: In es5 this example will look like this https://plnkr.co/edit/EdSONOCq9bfadD42jOj2?p=preview. Sorry, but why we pass object with descendants property?

Comment: Because otherwise only direct children are returned but no other descendants. Because the items are project two levels deep children only won't work. Thanks for the ES5 Plunker!